# socket io react client connection closes inmediately after creating it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket, socket.io, fastapi

I have a FastAPI Python server which supports sockets connections. I try to connect through a React client using socket.io-client. The problem is that the socket is created correctly but closes right after.
This is how the Python server provides the interface to connect to the sockets:

```py
import socketio
sio = socketio.AsyncServer(cors_allowed_origins="*", async_mode="asgi")
# define an asgi app
socketio_app = socketio.ASGIApp(sio, socketio_path="/")

@sio.event
async def connect(sid, environ):
    print("connect ", sid)
    player_id = environ.get("HTTP_PLAYER_ID")
    game_id = environ.get("HTTP_GAME_ID")
    # if the parameters are not present, the connection is rejected
    if not player_id or not game_id:
        return False
    await s

io.save_session(sid, {"player_id": player_id, "game_id": game_id})
    sio.enter_room(sid, "g" + game_id)
    sio.enter_room(sid, "p" + player_id)
    print("connect ", sid, "player_id ", player_id, "game_id ", game_id)
```

then it is mounted into the app as follows:

```py
app.mount("/socket.io", socketio_app)

origins = ["*"]
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)
```

This is my client file in which I create the socket:

```js
import { io } from "socket.io-client"

// hardcoded values for headers
const gameId = 1;
const playerId = 1;

const createSocket = (uri) => {
    const socket = io(uri, {
        extraHeaders: {
            game_id: gameId,
            player_id: playerId
        },
        transports: ["websocket"],
        autoConnect: true,

    // Listen for events
    socket.on("connection", () => console.log("websocket connected"));
    
    return socket;
}

const gameSocket = createSocket("http://localhost:8000/")

export {gameSocket};
```

The created socket is then imported into this file:

```js
import { gameSocket } from "./createSocket"
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"

const useSocket = () => {
    const [connected, setConnected] = useState(true);

    const handleConnChange = () => {
        setConnected(gameSocket.connected)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        gameSocket.on("connect", handleConnChange);
        gameSocket.on("disconnect", handleConnChange);

        return () => {
            gameSocket.removeListener("connect", handleConnChange);
            gameSocket.removeListener("disconnect", handleConnChange);
        }
    })

    return {
        gameSocket: gameSocket,
        isConnected: connected
    }
}

export default useSocket;
```

I finally use "useSocket" in this component:

```js
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react"
import useSocket from "./useSocket";

const GameRouter = () => {

    const [gameState, setGameState] = useState(-1);
    const [gameData, setGameData] = useState({});
    const [playerData, setPlayerData] = useState({});
    const { gameSocket } = useSocket();
    
    useEffect(() => {
        gameSocket.on("game_status", (data) => {
            setGameData(data);
            setGameState(data.state)
        })
    }, [gameData])

    return {
        <h1>websockets test<h1/>
    }
    
}

export default GameRouter;
```

when both server and client are running this is the log i get from the server:

```
INFO:     connection open
connect  UrwFItMNGGWN4FLaAAAT
INFO:     connection closed
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me. Thanks.

It seems that the socket is created disconnected. I tried setting autoConnect field to false and the manually call socket.connect() method but didn't work. I checked that the socketio versions I used for both server and client are compatible. Those are the only files in which sockets are modified or created. There are no extra components rendering so that the environment is isolated to test the connection work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the exact same problem, it seems like the server is not correctly parsing the headers you are sending. Try sending those values as a query instead of as a header. Then modify the server code accordingly.
Have a great day!

Comment: Omg I can not believe it worked. Thank you so much!